# How to decode XML entities in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, decode

How can I convert/decode a text in `&#1594;&#1604;&#1575;&#1605;&#1581;&#1587;&#1610;&#1606;` format to normal text? I'm using SQL server 2012. I just want to update all of them to normal text.

[image: Table]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482726/fix-html-encoded-text-stored-in-the-database . The short answer is that you really don't want to do this using SQL alone; .NET client code could easily do it (with [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode)).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I see but i want to do this just using sql functions.

Comment: How are you retrieving this data, though? What's the type of the `Firstname` and `Lastname` columns? If you know it's valid XML, you could just `CONVERT(XML, ...)` and back again.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `Firstname` and `Lastname` are type of `nvarchar`. I saved unicode text in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know Firstname and Lastname are valid when interpreted as XML, then this will do:

```
UPDATE _table_
SET Firstname = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(XML, FirstName)), 
Lastname = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(XML, LastName))
```

The XML parser will decode the entities for you.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason Jeroen's answer doesn't seem to work for me in SQL Server 2016.

The function below works... same principle, just executed differently.

```
create function dbo.xmlDecode (@string nvarchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
begin
    return cast(@string as XML).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)' )
end;
```